# Covariance parameter estimates table in R

Tags: r, covariance, lme4

I have created a random intercept and slope model (`lmer`) and need to inspect the covariances of the random effects to see which is significant.

I've seen that SAS outputs provide a *'covariance parameter estimates'* table as part of the model summary - see section *'Output 56.2.6 Repeated Measures Analysis'* of [PROC MIXED](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect031.htm#statug.mixed.mixx2c)

Is there a way of doing this (and obtaining p values for each covariance) in R?

Comment: Assuming you are using `lme4::lmer` - what covariance matrix do you want. `summary(yourmodel)` shows the correlation of the fixed effect (you can extract cov matrix using `cov(yourmodel)` and cor `cov2cor(vcov(yourmodel))` - probably a method in lme4 to do the latter step. `VarCorr(yourmodel)` to extract RE variances.

Comment: Yes, lme4. I am looking for the covariances of the random effects. I have extracted and created a data frame using: >as.data.frame(Varcorr(mymodel). Now I would like to test the significance of each covariance.

Comment: okay, so you are wanting to test the significance that each RE var-cov is not equal to zero? I dont think lme4 directly support this  - as an alternative you could compare models with different RE using the conditional AIC. (ps ive added the lme4 tag to attract attentoin)

Comment: TOC, Ive edited your question - can you check it still represents what you want please?

Comment: Thank you. Question editing much appreciated. Previous advice was to use LRT's to establish whether individual covariances were significant. I've used LRT's to compare models and to look at individual RE's but was not sure how to achieve this for individual covariances.

Comment: perhaps of interest http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find this in the output of the summary of your model:

```
x <- lm(formula)
y <- summary(x)
print(y$cov.unscaled)
```

From the documentation of `?summary`:

> cov.unscaled   a p x p matrix of (unscaled) covariances of the `coef[j],
>   j=1, …, p`.